# Angular Material Button Disable Style Change

Tags: css, angularjs, button, material-design, angular-material

form.html

```
<md-button class="md-raised md-primary pull-right formPage" ng-disabled="formPage.$invalid" ng-click ="submit()">SAVE</md-button>
```

css

```
.md-button.md-raised.md-primary.formPage {
    position: right !important;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color:#008cba;    
}
```

Button is disabled but it has custom color from my css. How can i show the default disable style or maybe change button color if it is disable ?

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pyo29odg/2/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the css should be

```
.md-button.md-raised.md-primary.formPage:not([disabled])
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/apxbutmf/

Comment: I thought about this logic, but couldn't find out how can i add color when it is not disabled. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When the button is disabled a new class comes up to your button with name called like `disabled`. Check it and update your css as below.

```
.md-button.md-raised.md-primary.formPage:not(.disabledclassname) {
    position: right !important;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color:#008cba;    
}
```

Comment: That didn't work. I have updated the question with Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding following css class worked for me (Angular-Material v12 Button mat-stroked):

```
.mat-stroked-button.mat-button-disabled.mat-button-disabled {    

color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #008cba

}
```